# Recycler View as part of a Scroll View

Tags: android, scrollview, android-recyclerview

I'm developing an app that has an UI pretty similar to Play Store. It is organized as a multiple panels one above another. First it has a panel containing a photo. Under that it has another panel containing some text and a custom background color. Under that it has another photo and finally it has a Linear Layout with vertical orientation containing a pretty long list of little views filled dynamically at runtime. I have all this inside a Scroll View, naturally.

The problem? That dynamic fill of the linear layout takes a long processor time and makes my app unresponsive during those inner views inflation. So I thought to replace the linear layout by a Recycler View. And the performance is awesome!

So? Well... Not everything is so awesome. I can't scroll the Recycler View because it's inside the Scroll View. And if I remove the Scroll View then I can't scroll the entire view (some things doesn't fit on the screen).

What's the best approach for fixing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not recommended to use a `RecyclerView` or `ListView` inside of a `ScrollView` precisely due to the double scrolling issues. `RecyclerView` is very robust and is prepared to receive headers, footers, etc. I see no reason why the entire layout could not be inside of a `RecyclerView` instead of a `ScrollView`

The `ViewHolder` implementation can include logic to inflate different layouts depending on what section should be next.

Pseudocode:

i.e.

```
if(currentAdapterItem == sectionA){
    useLayoutA();
} else{
    useLayoutB();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) instead of a normal `ScrollView`. It handles the nested scrolling quite well.